# Get maximum bandwidth of a Network Adapter

Tags: java, networking, adapter

I would like to know how do I obtain the max bandwidth of my network adapter.

I can read it when I open my Network settings panel (eg, Wired Connected - 100Mb/s), but I would to obtain this value diagrammatically. Wireless is not needed.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and coding in Java. I took a look in `NetworkInterface` and `InetAddress` and found nothing.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

**EDIT**

Running lshw -class network I found what I want:

```
lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 21
       serial: 00:10:18:2d:d6:19
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
```

How to get this from Java application?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link speed is available using `ethtool` for your adapter on Ubuntu. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-determine-ethernet-connection-speed/

This is the theoretical limit so the actual speed achieved can be less.

You can call a system command using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: This works very nice. If I call a system command, the machines running the java code must have the ethtool installed also, right?

Comment: correct. It also has to be in your PATH, unless you use the absolute path to use.

Comment: Well, I need something more generic. lshw -class network would be a better solution, using ProcessBuilder also?

Comment: ProcessBuilder is easier to use than plain Runtime.exec(). In particular try using `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` as it does in the Javadoc example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html